# Cucumber testing with data from inside the production DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I have data in the Production DB (Hashed+Salted) password and username which I want to test. I have read that I need to first populate the 'test.sqlite3' that cucumber generates, is this correct? If so how can I populate the test DB inside the feature file? Or is there a way to change the 'env.rb' in the support folder to use the Production DB?

Also, I heard the gem FactoryGirl is good for this type of thing. Is it as simple as just create a User object, fill out the user & pass for that instance, and then test that against the production DB?

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify what your end goal is with this. Are you looking to run smoke tests against your production app, or are you looking to copy some of the data from your production DB to the test DB and then run tests with that ?

Comment: I want to be able to run 'rails cucumber' it will then write data to the test.db from production and test if user & pass are correct for the admin user, then truncate all the data from the test.db

Comment: That sounds more like something that should be implemented as a unit test rather than a full feature test.  All you need is the hashed password (with salt) - SQL query to access from the production db -  and run it against whatever auth library you're suing to verify the valid password.  However, the whole idea sounds like a bad one since it means having your production DB credentials as well as your production apps admin password accessible in your tests - not great from a security point-of-view